# URL shortener with counter and/or stats

Tags: url-shortening

Is there any free URL shortener that supports counting? And maybe some logging? If possible, without any registration. As simple as tinyurl.com if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://goo.gl/ can do it, and it seems it has more advanced stats. Specifically adding `.info` to the end of the URL to get some detailed analytics.

Answer (score 1):

http://ez.gd is free and tracks your clics. The difference is that you can choose to receive a daily report in your email.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one: [smal.us](http://smal.us)

It avoid shortening of spam virus-related sites, it is secure and code behind analytic research.